# Non existence of a polynomial between two vectorspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let be $V$ the vector space of the sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\varphi: V \rightarrow V,(x_1,x_2,...) \mapsto (x_2,x_3,...)$

Show that there is no polynomial such that $f \in \mathbb{C}[x] \backslash \{0\} $ with $f(\varphi)=0$

My idea:
I was thinking about that I could eventually build up a matrices from these polynomials, checking it's characteristic polynomial and after using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem finding a conclusion, but I'm totally struggling how should I start solving the problem. I would appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton would (should it apply) give you that polynomial, but here you are to prove that no polynomial works. Again, by C-H it is essential that $V$ is infinite dimensional, and the solution must reflect that. Hint: Assume contrariwise that a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $m$ would work. What would $f(\phi)$ do to a vector whose only non-zero component is at position $m+1$?

Comment: could you eventually be a little bit more detailed I'm still extremely struggling with this prove.

Comment: Try some examples. What is $p(\varphi)$ when $p=x^2+x$? When $p=5x^3-x^2+1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, let there exist a non zero polynomial $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\,a_ix^i\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $f(\phi)=0$. Let $g=\{g_1,g_2,\cdots\}\in V$. Then $f(\phi)(g)=(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\,a_i\phi^i)\, (g)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\,a_i(g_{i+1},g_{i+2},\cdots)$. Thus,

$a_0g_1+a_1 g_2+a_2g_3+\cdots +a_ng_{n+1}=0$ and this equation is true for all possible choices of complex numbers $g_1,...,g_{n+1}$. From this we can conclude that the $n+1$ variable polynomial $a_0X_0+...+a_nX_n$ must be identically zero. This forces $a_0=...=a_n=0$, contrary to the assumption that $f(x)$ is a non zero polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Promoting the comment to an answer.

Assume contrariwise that a degree $n$ non-zero polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_x^i\in\Bbb{C}[x]$, $a_n\neq0$, would work. Consider the vector
$$x=(0,\ldots,1,0,\ldots)$$
where the only non-zero component $1=x_{n+1}$ appears at position $n+1$. It follows that the first component of $f(\phi)(x)=(a_n,?,?,\ldots)$ is non-zero. After all, of the vectors $a_i\phi^2(x)$ only the term $a_n\phi^n(x)=(a_n,0,0,\ldots)$ has a non-zero first component. Therefore $f(\phi)$ is not the zero function and we have run into a contradiction.